# Axios Type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, axios

class.ts

```
axiosInstance = axios.create();

getPage(config: AxiosRequestConfig) {
  return this.axiosInstance
    .request(config)
    .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```

index.ts

```
class.getPage(config).then((response: any) => {
  let page = response.data;

  console.log(page);
});
```

In my Index.ts i dont want to write `response: any`. Somehow I am to stupid to find out what type respone gives / has. `AxiosResponse` is wrong because I return the `axiosInstance`.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `getPage`, `.then` return `AxiosResponse<any, any>` and `.catch` return `console.error(error)` so type respone is `void | AxiosResponse<any, any>`

[image]

if in catch you **throw an error** instead return **console.error()** function, the type will be **AxiosResponse<any, any>**

[image]

Comment: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void | AxiosResponse<any, any>'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)

Comment: @Unknown I have updated the answer so you understand it better

Comment: Thanks, that little detail was the key. Learned something new, thanks!